# Does any one which version of the android introduce the webview auto check SSID?

Tags: android, webview, chromium, privacy

We have some privacy issue in our product when user not agree the T&C, but the webview auto check the network status, which caused the SSID be called many times in background.

Below is the code and repo link, does any one known which android version introduced this function?

https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/net/+/master/android/java/src/org/chromium/net/NetworkChangeNotifierAutoDetect.java
[image: code snapshot]

Thanks very much.

I have submit a issue to tracking it https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1457870,  and search for other solution now.